rsync over network to an external hard drive. Operation not permitted (1)
I want to backup some shared folders from my synology NAS to an external hard drive on my mac. Synology offers Hyper Backup using rsync for this kind of task. Since I can't get a task setup in Hyper Backup without it complaining about different errors, I figured I would just start by nailing the plain rsync side and then worry about Hyper Backup.
So far, the sync is successful as long as my rsync module's path points to a directory located on my main drive (i.e. /Users/bpjobin/directory). If I change it to one located in /Volumes, the sync won't work and throw me a error.
rsync.conf (on my Mac)
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsync.log


[nas_backup_test]
  use chroot = false
  path = /Volumes/Untitled                 <-- This does not work.
  #path = /Users/bpjobin/rsync_test         <-- This works.
  uid = root                                <-- Either root or bpjobin changes nothing.
  gid = wheel                               <-- Either wheel or staff changes nothing.
  list = yes
  read only = no
  write only = no
  secrets file = /etc/rsync/rsyncd.secrets
  auth users = bpjobin                      <-- User has root permissions.
  hosts allow = *

Command ran from NAS
rsync -avz files bpjobin@<ipaddress>::nas_backup_test
The error...
building file list ... done
files/
rsync: failed to set times on "files" (in nas_backup_test): Operation not permitted (1)
files/book_1.txt
files/book_2.txt
files/book_3.txt
rsync: mkstemp "files/.book_1.txt.fBoMAq" (in nas_backup_test) failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: mkstemp "files/.book_2.txt.4igwAi" (in nas_backup_test) failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: mkstemp "files/.book_3.txt.mU7q7t" (in nas_backup_test) failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: failed to set times on "files" (in nas_backup_test): Operation not permitted (1)

sent 243 bytes  received 497 bytes  296.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1464) [sender=3.1.2]

Permissions on both directories
➜  ~ ls -la /Volumes/Untitled
total 0
drwxrwxrwx   5 bpjobin  staff  160  9 May 09:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root     wheel  640  9 May 08:24 ..
drwxrwxrwx   4 bpjobin  staff  128  9 May 08:24 .Spotlight-V100
drwxrwxrwx   3 bpjobin  staff   96  9 May 08:24 .fseventsd
drwxr-xr-x   2 bpjobin  staff   64  9 May 09:22 files

➜  ~ ls -la /Users/bpjobin/rsync_test
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 bpjobin  staff          96  9 May 09:27 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 106 bpjobin  staff        3392  9 May 09:27 ..
drwx------    5 bpjobin  _lpoperator   160  9 May 09:21 files

UPDATE
I should add that the following command work.
rsync -avz files bpjobin@<ipaddress>:/Volumes/Untitled
So the problem lies in the rsync.conf module parameters...

rsync doesnt copy permissions to external drive and rsync command not preserving permissions   Conclusion: This question belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com (unless you are an ubuntu freak/user)??

"If I change it to one located in /Volumes, the sync won't work and throw me a error"  and  "I should add that the following command work. .../Volumes/..."  Please be clear about what is giving the problem....

"If I change it to one located in /Volumes, the sync won't work and throw me a error" meaning that I modified the path in the rsync.conf file.
[nas_backup_test]   use chroot = false   path = /Volumes/Untitled
The first instance still uses the module to rsync:
rsync -avz files bpjobin@<ipaddress>::nas_backup_test
while the second instance uses the absolute path:
rsync -avz files bpjobin@<ipaddress>:/Volumes/Untitled

You may be running into problems with macOS' privacy protection system, which considers external drives private by default and restricts access based on the "application" doing the access, not the user. Using host:target connects via ssh, and the ssh daemon may've been granted access; using host::target uses connects to an rsync daemon, which probably hasn't. See "On Catalina, how can a cronjob get permission to touch files on a USB disk?" (though in that case the "app" is cron, not rsync).
